# Python Script in Azure to Detect Vulnerable Ports

Tags: python, powershell, azure

I'm essentially trying to translate a Powershell script into a Python script. The script is used to scan all virtual machines within an Azure subscription. It checks to see if their ports are open to the world, and if they are, changes them to be open to only my machines.

The Powershell script is as follows.

```
Add-AzureRmAccount

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName #####

$nsgs=Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup

foreach ($nsg in $nsgs)
{

    $rules=$nsg.SecurityRules

    foreach($rule in $rules)
    {

        if ($rule.SourceAddressPrefix -eq "*")
        {

            $nsg | Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name $rule.Name -Priority $rule.Priority -Protocol $rule.protocol -Access $rule.access -SourcePortRange $rule.SourcePortRange -DestinationAddressPrefix $rule.DestinationAddressPrefix -DestinationPortRange $rule.DestinationPortRange -Direction $rule.Direction -SourceAddressPrefix "##.##.##.###/##"  | Set-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup

         }

    }

}
```

Comment: I see what you are doing, but there is nothing which can tole us what issue you got. So what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

The Python package will allow you to do this is azure 2.0.0rc5:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/azure/2.0.0rc5

Please note that this is a release candidate, but should be stable soon.

Even if not directly network oriented, this sample might help you:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/virtual-machines-python-manage

Also, the whole documentation is on readthedocs:
http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/